# Can we add a new API to azure API management from developer portal?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I have created a API management,here we can add manually required API's from portal. My question is can we add new API from Developer portal of Azure API management( i.e Dynamically).

I created a API Management- Called Hospital API Management.
I added Patient, Doctors API to it manually and published that API management.
Now i want to add new API Called Medications, for it i need to go to azure portal there i again i need to add, instead doing this process manually can we do this task dynamically so that new api will be added to "Hospital API Management"

Comment: The APIs can be added only from the Publisher portal. The Developer portal is intended to be exposed to the developers/vendors who are going to consume your APIs. Since you are the administrator of the API, you should be adding/modifying APIs through Publisher portal.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by John , APIs can be added only from the Publisher portal. The Developer portal is intended to be exposed to the developers/vendors who are going to consume your APIs. Since you are the administrator of the API, you should be adding/modifying APIs through Publisher portal.